# How can I increase the accuracy of Fibonacci implementation for large n?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm using Binet's Formula to calculate Fibonacci number for large n

Binet's Formula:
[image: Binet's Formula:]

my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def calc_fib(n):
  if (n <= 1):
  return n

  root_5    = 5 ** 0.5
  phi_n   = ((root_5 + 1) / 2) ** n
  alpha_n = ((root_5 - 1) / 2) ** n

  fn = round((phi_n - alpha_n) / root_5)
  return fn

n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n))
```

$ ./fibonacci.py
200
280571172992512015699912586503521287798784. (wrong)

the correct result is: 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525

the problem is that for very large n, say n = 200, the result is not accurate, I think because of the floating-point calculations, How can I change my code so I can get more accurate results?

Comment: Are you able to use an iterative method to compute the fibonacci number?

Comment: no, because for very large number you will get time_out error or you will run out of memory

Comment: I guess if you're computing an insanely high index fibonacci number, that could be an issue (tested it, python crashes when trying to compute the 1,000,000th fibonacci number). If your indices are within a couple thousand though, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I recommend using decimal.Decimal here.

Comment: decimal.Decimal  will round more and more so It will also provide wrong results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Binet's formula is that you need increasing accuracy to do the calculations, and floating point doesn't give you that.

There's a few ways to compute Fibonacci numbers efficiently. Here's my favourite, that isn't (explicitly) iterative, and has roughly the right runtime complexity:

```
def fib(n):
    X = 1<<(n+2)
    return pow(X, n+1, X*X-X-1) % X
```

This uses arithmetic with a number of bits that grows linearly with n, which I think is ok because the number of bits the result has grows linearly.

Alternative log(n) approaches are to use doubling formulae, use an integer version of Binet's formula (typically in an algebraic ring), or matrix power. I have a blog post describing them in more detail: https://blog.paulhankin.net/fibonacci2/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to correct `alpha_n` according to the formula:

```dart
alpha_n = ((1 - root_5) / 2) ** n
```

Comment: I edited the code in the question, this mistake did not affect the results for even n so the issue still the same.

Comment: @AmrRady Are you sure? The equation says `1 - root_5`.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the code as you pointed and I tried n = 200 again and still the same exact wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `decimal` library to increase precision:

```py
import time
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
getcontext().prec = 5000


sqrt_5 = Decimal(5)**Decimal(0.5)
phi = (Decimal(1) + sqrt_5) / Decimal(2)
phi_hat = (Decimal(1) - sqrt_5) / Decimal(2)
# Binet's formula
def Fibonacci_Binet(n):
  n = Decimal(n)
  return int((phi**n - phi_hat**n) / sqrt_5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 200  # Example Fibonacci number to calculate
    start_time = time.time()
    fib_binet = Fibonacci_Binet(n)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Fibonacci_Binet({n}) = {fib_binet}")
    print(f"Binet's formula took {end_time - start_time} seconds.")
```

This gives `280571172992510140037611932413038677189525`, which is correct.
Note that this will slow down your program as increased precision slows it down.