# C++ Nth Fibonacci Number Big Number Operation Problem

Tags: c++, c++11, math

I am working on the function that counts the Nth Number from the Fibonacci sequence.

I am using that algorithm to calculate it: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula

The problem is that I'm working on the big numbers and I have no idea how to store the data to prevent it from miscalculations and other errors :/

I saw some posts on stack and people suggest to divide the numbers into parts and calculate it that way - I think this is just a temporary and kinda primitive solution.

Is there any new, modern and not so complicated method of storing big numbers and operating (include math operations) on them without any errors??

Here's the Function:

```
std::string fibonacci(int n)
{

   long double numb = 1 / sqrt(5) * (pow(((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2),n) - pow(((1 - sqrt(5)) / 2),n));

   return std::to_string(numb);

}
```

Here's the output how the results change:

```
Input:  40
Output: 102334155.000000
Answer: 102334155
    
Input:  50
Output: 12586269025.000021
Answer: 12586269025

Input:  60
Output: 1548008755920.002930
Answer: 1548008755920

Input:  70
Output: 190392490709135.437500
Answer: 190392490709135

Input:  80
Output: 23416728348467744.000000
Answer: 23416728348467685

Input:  90
Output: 2880067194370825216.000000
Answer: 2880067194370816120

Input:  100
Output: 354224848179263111168.000000
Answer: 354224848179261915075
```

Comment: could you use an arbitrary precision floating point library? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: why are you using Binets formula? It looks like it is mainly of analytical interest but not quite well suited for numerical calculations, because there is a term that is much larger than the final result and it relies on floating points

Comment: btw the poor man's big number library is `std::string`. You can avoid overflow by doing all operations with strings only, the way you learned them at school

Comment: I think your errors might be related more to the imprecision of double at such sizes, as well as the imprecision of operations like pow. try using powl and long doubles to alleviate the issue a bit.
See this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154711/how-can-i-increase-the-accuracy-of-fibonacci-implementation-for-large-n

Comment: This looks like some online problem, please provide link to it, so all requirements are clear.

Comment: Fibonacci can be represented in matrix form, then calculating `n` element of this sequence is just calculating `n` power of matrix `((1, 1), (1, 0))`. Looks like you have to implement big numbers addition and multiplication.

Comment: @MarekR here's the link: https://edabit.com/challenge/Y7DMN2uY8FL3czf8o
Binet's Formula was there as the additional helpful information to solve the task.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number How can I do it with the strings?
I suspect that the solution is obvious, but I don't see it :/

Comment: I still don't know why you chose Binets formula. If you want fibonacci numbers, then addition is the only operation you need. You add two numers stored in string like you learned it in elementary school: start with the lowest digits, add them, remember the carry, continue with the next digit

Comment: btw you also didnt disclose yet what is the actual challange you are trying to solve. Typically online coding challenges are trick questions, they might ask you for example to calculate the last 5 digits of the N-th fibonacci number, then you need to realize that you never need to consider a number with more than 5 digits, ie plain `int` is sufficient.

Comment: I send the link again: https://edabit.com/challenge/Y7DMN2uY8FL3czf8o
Could you send the link to that string operations? I don't understand it at all :/
When it comes to sum of strings, I always associate operations of the type `"1" + "2" = "12"`

Comment: There is no builtin operator to do it. You have to do it by hand, like you learned it in elementary school. Take a pen and piece of paper to add 1224 with 4321. Carefully consider every single step you make to arrive at the final result. Then do the same in code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *@463035818_is_not_a_number*'s advices I managed to solve this error - add numbers in strings like this:

```
  1
  27
+ 59
----
  86
```

Also I change my original code a little bit:

1. I make `i` as a static to prevent function from starting counting all over from the beginning
2. Instead of constantly growing vector I used two strings - to count the third number we only need two previous ones, no more

Here's the function:

```
//Soln Author:  ernikus

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void reverseStr(std::string &str)
{
    int n = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        std::swap(str[i], str[n - i - 1]);
}


int char_to_int(const char character)
{
    return (int(character) - 48);
}



std::string fibonacci(int n)
{
    static std::string number[2]{ "0", "1" };

    const int limit = 201;

    if ((n - 1) <= 1)
        return number[n - 1];

    for (static int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        int size1 = number[0].size();
        int size2 = number[1].size();

        int size = size2;
        int diff = size - size1;

        std::cout << "Numer1: " << number[0] << "\tNumber2: " << number[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size1: " << size1 << "\tSize2: " << size2 << "\tHigh Size: " << size << "\tDiff: " << diff << std::endl;

        std::string result{};
        bool higher = false;

        for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            int trial{ 0 };


            if ((j - diff) >= 0)
            {
                trial = char_to_int(number[0][j - diff]) + char_to_int(number[1][j]);

                std::cout << "I.\tNum1: " << number[0][j - diff] << "\tNum2: " << number[1][j] << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                trial = char_to_int(number[1][j]);

                std::cout << "I.\tNum2: " << number[1][j] << std::endl;
            }


            if (higher == true)
            {
                trial++;
                higher = false;
            }

            if (trial >= 10)
            {
                higher = true;
                trial -= 10;
            }

            result += std::to_string(trial);

            std::cout << "Trial: " << trial << "\tResult: " << result << "\tJ: " << j << std::endl;
        }

        if (higher == true)
        {
            result += "1";
            higher = false;
        }

        reverseStr(result);

        std::cout << i << ". " << result << std::endl;

        number[0] = number[1];
        number[1] = result;

        if (i == n)
        {
            i++;
            return result;
        }
            
    }

    return "0";
}
```

The Output is very satisfactory :)

```
Input:  180
Output: 18547707689471986212190138521399707760
Answer: 18547707689471986212190138521399707760
Correct Answer!

Input:  190
Output: 2281217241465037496128651402858212007295
Answer: 2281217241465037496128651402858212007295
Correct Answer!

Input:  200
Output: 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525
Answer: 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525
Correct Answer!

Input:  222
Output: 11111460156937785151929026842503960837766832936
Answer: 11111460156937785151929026842503960837766832936
Correct Answer!

Input:  1111
Output: 6851462981265369536304298877223231154064355390623195419885661484162849735541256952762360871448156142552148460793441585691068131682370855135019896825808086317430648360941203391832868742715640036246053259136014253626356840914521594989Answer: 6851462981265369536304298877223231154064355390623195419885661484162849735541256952762360871448156142552148460793441585691068131682370855135019896825808086317430648360941203391832868742715640036246053259136014253626356840914521594989Correct Answer!

Input:  11111
Output: 515449135231559341621591189426925989418721609167804403107087312453694294479381404009230187092526675635022414542794904158934368158350216751867828729213516067642461147232232268304004580596220514978296704097915617589481297010691749471374967376304898014174716132125169572206688299944881902864940487579850754037243411123276226268998274067232370656873037885028569262362061989878439356579125363739644638605976667733232134130196207453194213358616463005487086631652051025004934485196108344869244852506414543015664379038338857611347469102943415360234480491921571800239803284078147859161629100936007246749423449323827401152142684138017539299637210829955409666781554035555164800825902557894478979141680264821730580654526990976167873657740460977594388216677737796493623940501749951993194553070912364327001564086186444836587037180810655016948562608480145057901528396467327800369394725748856906177005886944277609832795419082424474419033931754123200248752600310587761729439189440527073799320938597514569967706344559861576816209214912702962065352672071494639021231263782338510241176219316180788341549329905272081790433223099472061887224254193326845457247107409050092252994931668934553671721376871177693036352993174131508107261653495025271505086039171034392185521383307925723081097129536244468148375789733582131797176285225457221029865658845503179175504307577930140222583997281098099332145783930418777810346276337273420733754768191403158839413163368990092771464626510432292314209966950363068432367028332284209840897425718364670733733609565321893240873729315360915814803137552560521106490937691421540344502423323064743545226360364012549367167257038202145921861042955299329942301124074181956428710271876930526019606797077558959445434943166179407403375284366340173639269807373108055388080201746447050804598946499248800891171987624229020766742994219485280547337990630263452898332213470171667603200991268579583095661682595442200149483262133621860660302141160974707437100532341443580636798210704649175613121627855118061762876137389590812891131603206815601843823369210865672605256743142632199819790960079549275267815983406188538500072911327187912330503064073869613282412315795790671452556371408354045852898125070873750632615799469070245720036053071341314252092446074260578417947762296896685389368685659291620443322232933074723685001342680075497489
Answer: 515449135231559341621591189426925989418721609167804403107087312453694294479381404009230187092526675635022414542794904158934368158350216751867828729213516067642461147232232268304004580596220514978296704097915617589481297010691749471374967376304898014174716132125169572206688299944881902864940487579850754037243411123276226268998274067232370656873037885028569262362061989878439356579125363739644638605976667733232134130196207453194213358616463005487086631652051025004934485196108344869244852506414543015664379038338857611347469102943415360234480491921571800239803284078147859161629100936007246749423449323827401152142684138017539299637210829955409666781554035555164800825902557894478979141680264821730580654526990976167873657740460977594388216677737796493623940501749951993194553070912364327001564086186444836587037180810655016948562608480145057901528396467327800369394725748856906177005886944277609832795419082424474419033931754123200248752600310587761729439189440527073799320938597514569967706344559861576816209214912702962065352672071494639021231263782338510241176219316180788341549329905272081790433223099472061887224254193326845457247107409050092252994931668934553671721376871177693036352993174131508107261653495025271505086039171034392185521383307925723081097129536244468148375789733582131797176285225457221029865658845503179175504307577930140222583997281098099332145783930418777810346276337273420733754768191403158839413163368990092771464626510432292314209966950363068432367028332284209840897425718364670733733609565321893240873729315360915814803137552560521106490937691421540344502423323064743545226360364012549367167257038202145921861042955299329942301124074181956428710271876930526019606797077558959445434943166179407403375284366340173639269807373108055388080201746447050804598946499248800891171987624229020766742994219485280547337990630263452898332213470171667603200991268579583095661682595442200149483262133621860660302141160974707437100532341443580636798210704649175613121627855118061762876137389590812891131603206815601843823369210865672605256743142632199819790960079549275267815983406188538500072911327187912330503064073869613282412315795790671452556371408354045852898125070873750632615799469070245720036053071341314252092446074260578417947762296896685389368685659291620443322232933074723685001342680075497489
Correct Answer!
```